# Auto embeding Vimeo/Youtube in custom fields (tinyMCE editor)

Tags: custom-field, tinymce, embed, oembed, vimeo

I'm using 2 extra TinyMCE editors on my pages to add extra textfiels in my theme pages. I now realize that the auto-embed feature is not supported on content delivered thought custom fields. So i need to tell WordPress to enable this on these two extra custom fields.

Here is an example of the back-end part included in my functions.php file:

```
    function monster_meta_options() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $monster_tiny_1 = (isset($custom['monster_tiny_1'][0]) ? $custom['monster_tiny_1'][0] : '');
    //Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

    //TinyMCE field! :)
    $args = array('wpautop' => true, 'media_buttons' => true, 'quicktags' => true,'textarea_name' => 'monster_tiny_1');
    wp_editor( html_entity_decode($monster_tiny_1), 'lower-left', $args);   
}
```

This is an example of how i output my custom field on the front end. A custom page named om-monster.php

```
                        <div class="entry-content-left">
                        <?php 
                            $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'monster_tiny_1', true);
                            $monster_tiny_1 = (isset($custom_field) ? $custom_field : '');

                        if ($monster_tiny_1 != '') {

                            echo wpautop(html_entity_decode($monster_tiny_1));

                        } ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content-left -->
```

So how can i enable autoembed on the content written in the custom TinyMCE editor (should be the same as a normal text field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably best off using `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', html_entity_decode( $monster_tiny_1 ) );` instead of `echo wpautop(html_entity_decode($monster_tiny_1));` and similar, which will run the autoembed behavior.

Comment: Just tried it out myself, and Thank you! this works perfectly!

Comment: however i needed to add the code html_entity_decode to the variable because i use esc_attr when i put the information into the database. This is my working code 'echo apply_filters( 'the_content', html_entity_decode($monster_tiny_1) );'

Comment: `esc_attr()` is really meant as escaping for display in an HTML attribute. You should use something like `wp_kses_post()` for sanitizing before saving to the database.